# Compiler Error Message: CS0021

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

Anyone know why the following is not working?

**C#:**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        {
            using (command = new SqlCommand("select col1, col2 from table1 where id = @id", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = 1;
                connection.Open();

                using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    Div1.InnerHtml = reader.Read["col1"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div runat="server" id="Div1"></div>
```

**Error:**

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'
Line 32: Div1.InnerHtml = reader.Read["col1"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this

```
Div1.InnerHtml = reader.Read["col1"].ToString();
```

Into this

```
Div1.InnerHtml = reader["col1"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are applying wrong indexer on the SqlDataReader. [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx)

you can try like this

```
 Div1.InnerHtml = reader["your ColumnName"].ToString();
```

here it gives complete details of why that exception is raised [ERRor cs0021](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akd1d8x2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)